# Crash when app runs on simulator

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a problem that is my app just crash when it runs on device simulator.

> > reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.'

And it works well on real device. Someone have an idea how to solve it. Please let me know.

Thanks all for your support.

Comment: Remove derived data from xcode and clean build. Crash happens when you have modified entities .

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your comment. But, it still does not work.

Comment: delete application from  simulator and install again and try

Comment: Try to reset simulator

Comment: Maybe this will help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706505/core-data-application-is-crashing-in-iphone-device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706505/core-data-application-is-crashing-in-iphone-device)

Answer (score 0):

Just Delete and run the app from simulator not solved .Please share your code let me check .